# Selecting trait to inherit common method from in Scala

Tags: scala, inheritance, traits

Suppose that I create a class mixing in two traits, both of which implement a common method, as follows for instance:

```
abstract class Base {
    var x:Int
    def adder:Int
}

trait One extends Base {
    def adder() = {x+=2; x}
}

trait Two extends Base {
    def adder() = {x+=3; x}
}

class WhichOne(var x:Int = 10) extends Base with One with Two

println((new WhichOne()).adder())
```

At runtime, Scala of course complains since it has no idea which trait to prefer:

```
$ scala MixUpTraitImplems.scala 
MixUpTraitImplems.scala:18: error: class WhichOne inherits conflicting members:
  method adder in trait One of type ()Int  and
  method adder in trait Two of type ()Int
(Note: this can be resolved by declaring an override in class WhichOne.)
class WhichOne(val x:Int = 10) extends Base with One with Two
      ^
```

Of course, overriding adder() would mean that I go ahead and implement a new version of `adder`, but what if I don't want that? What if I want to use the implementation of `adder` explicitly contained in trait `One` or `Two`?

Comment: If you add the `override` keyword to `adder` methods in your traits, then the implementation mix in last (from left to right) will be picked. In this case, `Two`. But that's not a great design to rely on declaration order.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can specify this as a modifier to `super`: `override def adder() = super[One].adder()`. Also note that this is a compile-time error, *not* runtime!

Comment: Hm, not according to my version of IntelliJ. At least it doesn't flag it as an error until I call the interpreter on the script. Thanks.

Comment: IntelliJ sometimes misses these more complex inheritance and type system errors. If you run it from (say) SBT you will be able to see the compilation problem.

Comment: Building the project in IntelliJ (Ctrl+F9) will show you the actual compilation errors and warnings (on some changes `Rebuild project` is necessary). Don't trust the errors shown by it while typing: it can both miss actual errors and show fake ones.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to override the adder to just call the adder of the it's super class. In this case, it will be the rightmost trait/class that implements adder (in the example below, it will be the adder of the `One` trait).

```
class WhichOne(var x:Int = 10) extends Base with Two with One {
   override def adder() = super.adder()
}
```

Comment: Poster mentioned it was not an option for him to add an override.

Comment: It was not an option for him to add an override that requires him to re-implement the method. This one just says use the super (so not really reimplementing any logic here).

Comment: Generally speaking, `super` references the right-most mixed in `trait` always, then? If any?

Comment: This drills down to how scala solves the "diamond problem" with multiple inheritance. This [link](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/blog/2013/05/30/traits-how-scala-tames-multiple-inheritance/) has some more details. As a rule of thump, yes, the rightmost trait will usually be your first point of entry (so their methods will be executed first).